# Android How to back to sleep mode after staying awake(WAKE LOCK)

Tags: android

I 'm using Wake Lock to stay awake my phone.
I want to activate  sleep mode when I will push the button "Activate"

How can I activate sleep mode?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I activate sleep mode?

You don't. The phone will go to sleep after it has been inactive for the user-specified period and after any other application holding an acquired `WakeLock` releases it.